# How to convert a Set in Map to json in flutter with dart

Tags: json, flutter, serialization, deserialization

I'm new in flutter and I have a problem of json serialization with the following class:

```
class Profile {
  DatabaseReference _id;
  String userId;  // related to Google UserId
  Map<String,Set> attrs;  // String is the key and the Set includes all possible value
}
```

the Map in Profile Class have a String for key and a Set for its values, it'll be like:

```
attrs = [{"food":["beef","fish","pork"]},{"work_experience":["company1","company2"],...}]
```

Are there any good solutions to serialize/deserialize the class toJson/fromJson?

Answer (score 0):

Just pest your json file it will give Serialize model

https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this.

```
class Profile {
  var _id;
  String? userId; // related to Google UserId
  late Map<String, Set>
      attrs; // String is the key and the Set includes all possible value

  Profile.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    attrs = Map();
    var attrsVal = json["attrs"];
    attrsVal.forEach((e) {
      MapEntry entry = e.entries.first;
      attrs.putIfAbsent(entry.key, () => entry.value.toSet());
    });
  }

  toJson() {
    return Map<String, dynamic>()
      ..putIfAbsent("id", () => _id)
      ..putIfAbsent("userId", () => userId)
      ..putIfAbsent(
          "attrs", () => [attrs.map((k, v) => MapEntry(k, v.toList()))]);
  }

}
```